# Replace a string from folder and subfolder - Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to replace

/oracle/apps/xxsnc/ab  to /xxsnc/oracle/apps/ab

i tried

> find . -type f exec sed -i 's//oracle/apps/po//xxsnc/oracle/apps/ab/g' {} \;

its throwing error like sed: e expression #1, char  unknown to s

Pls help

Comment: try `find . -type f exec sed -i 's|/oracle/apps/po|/xxsnc/oracle/apps/ab|g' {} \;`

Comment: I want to replace the string in the files , which are inside the directory/subdirectory - I am modifing the the codes inside a directory/subdirectory

Comment: path must preceeed expression:exec - for Jens' answer

Comment: That Worked :) thanks.. Jens/Anubhava

Comment: needs to be `-exec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\/oracle\/apps\/xxsnc\/ab/\/xxsnc\/oracle\/apps\/ab/gc' {} \;
```

Using `\` (escape character).

The optional `c` flag in sed prompts before each change.